# How to space out a string based on a value

Tags: python, code-formatting

I am trying to space out the contents in a single `print()` statement by a specified width.  I'll only post the relevant code:

```
def print_formatted(number):
    # your code goes here
    width = len(convert(number, 2))

    for i in range(number):
        print(
            str(i + 1) + width + 
            str(convert(i + 1, 8)) + width + 
            str(convert(i + 1, 16)) + width + 
            str((convert(i + 1, 2)))
            )
```

I am aware that the concatenation `...+ width +` doesn't work.  I put it there to visualize what I my aim is.  I've read from the docs that `format()` is the function to go with but I haven't seen an implementation similar to what I am trying to do here.

A successful output:

```
    1     1     1     1
    2     2     2    10
    3     3     3    11
    4     4     4   100
    5     5     5   101
    6     6     6   110
    7     7     7   111
    8    10     8  1000
    9    11     9  1001
   10    12     A  1010
   11    13     B  1011
   12    14     C  1100
   13    15     D  1101
   14    16     E  1110
   15    17     F  1111
   16    20    10 10000
   17    21    11 10001
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what a successful input/output of your function would be?  That'd make this easier to tackle.

Comment: Check the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formatting options for this.  Unfortunately, you have to manually specify the maximum width because `print` doesn't have a way of knowing what the biggest thing that's going to be printed later is:

```
list_of_tuples = list(zip(
    range(10),
    range(0, 20, 2),
    range(0, 30, 3),
    [10**i for i in range(10)]
    ))

width = 10 # Has to be specified manually, unfortuntately.
for tup in list_of_tuples:
    print("\t".join(f"{number:>{width}}" for number in tup))

     0           0           0           1
     1           2           3          10
     2           4           6         100
     3           6           9        1000
     4           8          12       10000
     5          10          15      100000
     6          12          18     1000000
     7          14          21    10000000
     8          16          24   100000000
     9          18          27  1000000000
```

Comment: I did specify width manually so that part is fine.  But how would I apply this same logic to my existing code.

Comment: Make your `list_of_tuples`.  I don't have your `convert` function so I have no idea where you're getting the data from, but I don't want to.  Once you have the list of tuples, just paste the bottom half of my code block.

Comment: Thanks man.  I've accepted and upvoted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: @OnurOzbek Glad I could help.  Also, it seems as of this moment I'm [the only one](https://i.imgur.com/zT6ql1h.png) that upvoted your question  :-)  I confess I did it because I agree it was well-written.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
print(
    str(i + 1)+"{}".format("\t")+ 
    str(convert(i + 1, 8)) +"{}".format("\t")+
    str(convert(i + 1, 16)) +"{}".format("\t")+ 
    str((convert(i + 1, 2)))
     )
```

Comment: Yea but with this example, the space is way too off.  Where do I inser the `width` variable?

Comment: ```width = str("          ") #number of space do you want; "{}".format(width)```